# Form Rise-Input and repeat the text while filling CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form which currently works fine, only thing I would like it to do is when I fill the text, the placeholder also should show whatever I type in the field.

Lets say if I am filling First Name:
Bob The Builder, the place holder should also show the same 'Bob The Builder' instead of 'First Name'.

Below is the related code to it:

[Form-rise-click here for fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyowcgut/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input id="fname" type="text" class="cool"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lname" type="text" class="cool"/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" class="cool"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #999;
}

div.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.wrap div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, 
                      font-size .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, 
              font-size .2s ease-in-out;
}

.active {
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
} 

input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('input').on('focusin', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('label').addClass('active');
});

$('input').on('focusout', function() {
  if (!this.value) {
    $(this).parent().find('label').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just used **keyup()** of jquery. It is basically an event handler to the **keyup** of javascript event.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){    
  $(this).parent().find('label').text($(this).val())
});
```

Please check in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashwanth_t/tyowcgut/4/) for any doubts.

Here is a small suggestion for a better *UX*.

When the input value is empty you can give a small if condition to show its former placeholder. And we can mange that placeholder with the help of an attribute. for e.g here i'm using **name** to retrieve the placeholder.

Please check in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashwanth_t/tyowcgut/6/) for any doubts.

Hope this is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Use the following jQuery code as an example for the rest of your inputs.

```
$("#fname").keyup(function() {
    $("label[for='fname']").html($(this).val());
});
```

Description: You select the ID input (e.g. **#fname**) for which you want to change the value of the label that moves to top (e.g. label **fname**) to the value that you are currently typing.

Check the updated JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/NikolaosG/tyowcgut/3/

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help, this is exactly what I was looking for. All the answers are good. I was away from my machine since last two days, so couldnt respond.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the keyup event is the best way to handle this. But additionally, you use multiple event handlers for each input -- here's an alternate way to handle that scenario. Not that one is better or preferred, simply an option.

```js
$('input').on({
  focusin: function() {
    $(this).parent().find('label').addClass('active');
  },
  focusout: function() {
    if (!this.value) {
      $(this).parent().find('label')
        .removeClass('active');
    }
  },
  keyup: function() {
    var newText = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find('label').text(newText);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #999;
}

div.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.wrap div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, 
                      font-size .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, 
              font-size .2s ease-in-out;
}

.active {
  top: -25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
} 

input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input id="fname" type="text" class="cool" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lname" type="text" class="cool" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" class="cool" />
  </div>
</div>
```